# Custom Meteor autoform template

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have nested schemas. Using `{{> afQuickField name='work_item' template="myTemplate"}}` outputs the inputs in a very logical way, but for some of my more complex objects this isn't terribly practical. I'd like to set up a template where I can precisely place each input with some other html.

These are also (usually) arrays of objects, so the `.autoform-add-item` and `.autoform-remove-item` button functionality is very nice and I would like to keep it.

How would I define custom templates for particular nested schemas and call them in my main form?

**Have tried**

Creating a `<template name="afWorkItem_myTemplate">` named like my custom form templates extrapolated from the bootstrap3 form templates. I then try to call it like `{{> afWorkItem name='work_item' template="myTemplate"}}` but that did not work at all.

**update**

I tried to modify my custom `afArrayField` template to output different structures based on `arrayFieldName`. This seemed a little closer but still no cigar.

```
Template.afArrayField_autoupdate.helpers({
  whichTemplate: function(templateName){
    return this.arrayFieldName === templateName;
  }
});
```

Then in `afArrayField_autoupdate` template:

```
{{#if whichTemplate 'address'}}
  {{> afQuickField name=this.current.street options=afOptionsFromSchema template="autoupdate" placeholder="schemaLabel"}}
  <br />
  {{> afQuickField name=this.current.city options=afOptionsFromSchema template="autoupdate" placeholder="schemaLabel"}}
  {{> afQuickField name=this.current.state_id options=afOptionsFromSchema template="autoupdate" placeholder="schemaLabel"}}
  {{> afQuickField name=this.current.zip options=afOptionsFromSchema template="autoupdate" placeholder="schemaLabel"}}
  <br />
  {{> afQuickField name=this.current.address_type_id options=afOptionsFromSchema template="autoupdate" placeholder="schemaLabel"}}
  {{> afQuickField name=this.current.active_address options=afOptionsFromSchema template="autoupdate" placeholder="schemaLabel"}}
{{else}}
  {{> afQuickField name=this.name label=false options=afOptionsFromSchema template="autoupdate" placeholder="schemaLabel"}}
{{/if}}
```

Which came very close but all of my fields (including ones that are selects if I simply use the afQuickField method in the else block) came out as text inputs.

Comment: When you tried creating your custom `afWorkItem` input, did you call [AutoForm.addInputType](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#defining-custom-input-types) to let AutoForm know about it?

Comment: @mark indeed I did. I had to create the html/js separately as the package is not yet compatible with autoform 5.0+. I will be posting later that I did get this to work though somewhat hackily.

Comment: Oh ok. There's probably a non-hacky way to do what you want, but I'm not sure what you've tried yet, so I'll wait for your update. It's very odd that they show up as select inputs in the `else` block but not in the `if` block... some other things you could try for fun: in the `afArrayField` template, what happens if you add `type="select"` to the `afQuickField`s, or perhaps change them to `afSelect`s?

Comment: @mark actually I had mixed this up with another question I had asked, probably in my late night haze of developing too long. Your suggestion seems to be spot on, I hadn't called addInputType. I shall try that today. Please suggest that in an answer!

Comment: No problem, that happens to me all too often. I've posted an answer -- fingers crossed it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add a custom `afWorkItem` input type, you'll have to call [AutoForm.addInputType](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#defining-custom-input-types) to let AutoForm know about it. Not sure what you meant exactly by the template not working at all, but this might be a reason. There are plenty of examples in the form of the [built-in input types](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/tree/master/inputTypes).

Comment: If you look at `afArrayField`, there's a lot of functionality in using that template that I don't want to lose (add/remove array element, essentially). I'm really shooting to just change out where it calls "afQuickField", so I think there's gotta be some way to change which template THAT chooses, so that I can have my custom template inside the `afArrayField` one

Comment: If im not mistaken, youre trying to show select fields where you have the afquickfields. Have you tried adding a type=select or using afSelect altogether?

Comment: I'm trying to... show a custom layout for part of a form (certain nested schemas) inside the afArray template where it would normally just spit out form inputs based on the nested schema. This is so I can control the HTML, I have other HTML elements I want that aren't put out automatically, AND also keep the add/remove from array feature that's baked into afArray.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been quite busy. I guess I'm unclear what it is you are observing that seems incorrect. Does nothing show up at all when you swap in the afworkitem template? In your custom afarrayfield template do the fields still show up as text inputs even after declaring the type as select?